# Java program with reload4j: how to write events to the system event log?

Tags: log4j, reload4j

The old log4j 1.x is not longer supported, but a fork called reload4j solved its main security issues and it's being released, so that old applications can work without a rebuild.

So I replaced log4j 1.x with reload4j for an old java application.
The application works, but I get errors because the class NTEventLogAppender was removed and events cannot be written to the system event log.

Is there an appender that can be used instead of NTEventLogAppender?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an appender that can be used instead of NTEventLogAppender. You can use the EventLogAppender, which is available in the newer versions of log4j, including the reload4j fork.

The EventLogAppender writes log events to the Windows Event Log. You can configure it to write to a specific Event Log and specify the events' source. Here's an example configuration:

```
<appender name="EVENTLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.EventLogAppender">
  <param name="Application" value="MyApplication" />
  <param name="Server" value="localhost" />
  <param name="Log" value="Application" />
  <param name="SourceType" value="MyApplication" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

In this example, the EventLogAppender is configured to write to the "Application" event log on the local machine and uses "MyApplication" as the source of the events. You can customize the values as per your requirements.

Add this appender to your log4j configuration, and events will be written to the Windows Event Log.

Comment: When I try something like that, I have the error:
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows. java.langClassNotfoundException org.apache.log4j.EventLogAppender (...)

Anyway I decided now to redirect the logging to a file and don't use system event logging